# google Play store app update issue with assets

Tags: android, react-native

Once upload new build on playstore and updating the app from play store all assets are messed up. It is not happen with all device but some device are facing such issue.

I have tried multiple time gradlew clean and gradlew build command before submitting build on playstore but issue persists.

Comment: The question is not clear can you please provide more information, like what you mean by assets are messed up?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this issue is to make sure that all your assets are correctly named and included in the correct folder. Make sure that you don't have any duplicate assets in the project. Also, make sure that the asset is properly referenced in the code.

Another solution is to try to clear the cache of the device. This can be done by going to Settings > Apps > Your App > Storage > Clear Cache.

Finally, if the above solutions don't work, then you can try to rebuild the app from scratch and then upload it on the Play Store.